# Characterization of KL divergence for continuous variables?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, entropy

This is an analog of an older question:

[What characterizations of relative information are known?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224559/what-characterizations-of-relative-information-are-known)

With the modification that I’m interested in the case when the distribution is over something that’s not a finite set. For example, for compactly supported distributions over an interval equipped with some measure. The definition of the KL divergence in this case is found as the third equation in the defintions section in the [relevant wikipedia entry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224559/what-characterizations-of-relative-information-are-known).

**I would like to know whether there’s an axiomatic characterization of this, generalizing the characterizations in the discrete case.**

My limited intuition (as a non-information-theorist) is that this could be tricky, for I’m reminded that there’s a nice characterization of ordinary entropy of discrete distributions due to Fadeev, which lacks an obvious generalization to the differential/continuous entropy. There’s a relevant discussion of this issue in [another older post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262577/is-there-an-axiomatic-characterization-of-the-entropy-of-a-continuous-random-var?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an axiomatic characterization of the entropy of a continuous random variable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262577/is-there-an-axiomatic-characterization-of-the-entropy-of-a-continuous-random-var)

Comment: @RW relative entropy/KL divergence is a different object from the one discussed in the linked post (ordinary entropy) , with different properties.

Comment: I'm the author of the other question, and I agree that ordinary entropy and relative entropy for continuous distributions are different enough objects that this deserves to be a separate question.  Ordinary entropy, unlike relative entropy, varies when you change variables, and it has no positive definiteness property.  So I would naively expect relative to entropy to have a different (and better) axiomatic characterization.

Answer (score 1):

Skilling wrote a paper with an axiomatic approach to the relative entropy [1] as a tool for inductive reasoning. And furthermore, there is another paper by Caticha and Preuss [2], which nicely summarises Skilling's approach.

[1] John Skilling (1988). The axioms of maximum entropy.

[2] Ariel Caticha, Roland Preuss (2003). Maximum Entropy and Bayesian Data Analysis: Entropic Priors.